# Can i get all my posts(profile feed) using Facebook Graph API explorer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can i get ALL my posts(my Profile feed) using Graph API explorer?

I tried using https://graph.facebook.com//posts?limit=500

but it doesn't seem to give me everything(even increasing the limit doesn't work) which 
means it given only a predefined number of posts.

Is there a way to get all posts by me from the time i joined Facebook(because i can get them by scrolling down on my Wall which means facebook has stored them).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Getting all the posts from facebook using graph api is not possible.

Comment: Silly question, but you're using the pagination links that are returned from the API and using them to add an offset and retrieve the second set of 500 posts, right?

Comment: @Igy can you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#paging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get Access Token

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Then

https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_ID/feed?access_token=FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN

This post might also be helpful:

[How to show facebook feed messages from my site without access_token?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9663700/#9663836)

Comment: The person already knows how to use the Grapth API explorer basics so why did you repeat that? You need to address the pagination too. The last link you gave (show Facebook feed without access_token) were not related to the question at all

Answer (score 0):

**You do not need an access token!**

```
$url = 'url_pulled_from_database';
$url = str_replace('http://www.', 'http://graph.', $url);
$get_id = file_get_contents($url);
$get_id = json_decode($get_id, true);   
$fbID = $get_id['id'];

//THEN CALL THE FUNCTION        
fb_parse_feed($fbID, $maxnumber);
```

I cant take credit for the fb_parse_feed function, but you can find it here
https://gist.github.com/banago/3864515